# Print at console the information of a website

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, nsstring

I've made a server that runs a https website. I want to print out the information of the website on my console in Xcode.

To do that, I added the following to my `ViewController.m`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSError *error;
    NSString *address = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"https://54.169.239.78:3001"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:address];
    NSString *theWeb = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@", theWeb);
}
```

However, the results are always `(null)`. In addition, I get an error:

> NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed
>   (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)

Even though I have allowed App Transport Security in my Info.plist

What's wrong?

Comment: Log `error` and see what the problem is.

Comment: See [these search results](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL+%22-9813%22). It probably has to do with the SSL certificate on your server.

Comment: Are you using a self-signed certificate?

Comment: Yes I am using a self-signed cert. Is there a way to test whether I can retrieve the info of a website that uses a self-signed cert?

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with your certificate only. If you have properly set your plist like this.[image]

If you want to verify this thing just change the url (**https://developer.apple.com/**) of the website in your code and update your code as:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSError *error;
    NSString *address = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"https://developer.apple.com/"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:address];
    NSString *theWeb = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@", theWeb);
}
```

I have tried this it has displayed the content.

You actually need real SSL certificate. Here is the link for certificates regarding details and self signed certificates have also been discussed over here:
[Certificate details](https://blog.httpwatch.com/2013/12/12/five-tips-for-using-self-signed-ssl-certificates-with-ios/)